# Customizable floating button in Android

Tags: android, button, floating-action-button

Android allows us to create a floating button

I have found many resources for that.

I want to customize that button, and by that i mean to change the size of it
I want it to be rectangle in dimensions of (20% of screen width and 15% of screen height)

is this something doable ?  if so how?

Comment: By floating button do you mean floating action button ?

Comment: yes i mean that

Comment: But why fab for your requirement? You can use a normal button too if you want rectangular shape

Comment: @VivekMishra will the button be floating on top of other apps?

Comment: that is called floating widget not floating button

Comment: then i am asking the wrong question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this is not the recommended way of Using FAB.See here:
https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#

For changing the Shape of the Floating action button, I think you have to make your own implementation of FloatingActionButton i.e a Custom FAB with Your own implementation of Custom Shape.

Answer (score 1):

your answer is here use that:

https://github.com/robertlevonyan/customFloatingActionButton

Comment: Don't post just link in the answer. Posted the relevant content from the link in answer too. As if someday link goes down then, this answer will have no meaning